# Are JUnit Testsuite metrics counted recursively for testsuites within testsuites?

Tags: xml, junit

For example if I have

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="suite1" tests=? failures=? errors=? time="2">
        <testsuite name="suite2" tests=? failures=? errors=? time="3">
            <testcase name="test1">
                <failure message="Stackoverflow"/>
            </testcase>
            <testcase name="test2"/>
            <testcase name="test3"/>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Are the question marks filled recursively adding up failures and test number for all children and their children and so on or are only direct children considered?